# Php Leaderboard issue

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so a client posts feedback on a manager and they get a total score. What I want this page to do per month is to create a COUNT of the number of submissions that manager has received with their total score for the total amount of feedback received,

The code at the moment counts the number of $managers name appeared in the database however where its only counting the manager name once! I have two feedbacks for Manager A however count only shows one for example.

The total score created is the total score for all managers and not for the individual manager.

Here is the code:

```
<table style="border-collapse: separate;    border-spacing: 10px;    cellspacing: 47px;    width: 100%;">
<tr>

<td>Manager</td><td>Submissions</td><td>Total Count</td>

</tr>
<?php

 //This page is maangers vs managers on feedback recieved and feedback score overall

//$m = date("m");

$m = '09';

include "dbconnect.php";

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `clientsfeedback` WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."' ORDER BY `manager` ASC");

//SELECT * FROM `clientsfeedback` WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '09' ORDER BY `manager` ASC

            $result=mysql_query($sql); 

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

            $manager = $row['manager'];

            $tc = $row['totalscore'];

            $manager = $row['manager'];

            $count = ("Select count(".$manager.") FROM clientsfeedback WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."'"); //Spot on

            $c = ("Select SUM(totalscore) FROM `clientsfeedback` WHERE `manager` = ".$manager." AND MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."' ORDER BY `manager` ASC");

            $q = mysql_query($c);
            $rt = mysql_fetch_array($q);


            $ct = count($count);

 echo "<tr><td>".$manager."</td><td>".$ct."</td><td>".$rt[0]."</td></tr>";
            }

?>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance

SAMPLE DATA
    --
    -- Table structure for table `clientsfeedback`
    --

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientsfeedback` (
  `id` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manager` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `securityofficer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `siteid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sitename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `duedate` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `stuniform` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `stattitude` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `stcustomercare` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `docsai` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `docshealthnsafety` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `docsregisters` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `oppatrols` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `opsitetraining` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `oplicences` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `supmanagervisits` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `supcontract` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `supresponce` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `opmcomments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customerservicedeliverycmt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `totalscore` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `submitteddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `completedhow` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `completedby` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `confirmed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `superior` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `clientsfeedback`
--

INSERT INTO `clientsfeedback` (`id`, `manager`, `securityofficer`, `siteid`, `sitename`, `group`, `duedate`, `stuniform`, `stattitude`, `stcustomercare`, `docsai`, `docshealthnsafety`, `docsregisters`, `oppatrols`, `opsitetraining`, `oplicences`, `supmanagervisits`, `supcontract`, `supresponce`, `opmcomments`, `customerservicedeliverycmt`, `totalscore`, `submitteddate`, `completedhow`, `completedby`, `confirmed`, `superior`) VALUES
(1, 'Bennett', 'Brian', '', '', 'ABC', '22/09/2016', 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 'hello', 'hello', 18, '2016-09-29 16:02:42', 'telephone', 'Dylon', 1, 0),
(2, 'Manager2', 'Pip', '', '', '', '', 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'None', 'None', 14, '2016-09-12 09:22:57', '', 'Manager2', 1, 0),
(3, 'Bennett', 'Manager2', '', '', '', '', 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 'None', 'None', 14, '2016-09-12 09:29:08', '', '', 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your count sql is slightly incorrect.

If you want to get the count for all records for all managers for the given month then it should be:

```
$count = ("Select count(manager) FROM clientsfeedback WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."'");
```

Whereas if you want to get the count for all records for a specific manager for the given month then you need to limit it, for example:

```
$count = ("Select count(manager) FROM clientsfeedback WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."' AND manager = '".$manager."'");
```

To get a list of unique managers, you'll need to add a `GROUP BY` in your initial `SELECT` statement, for example:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `clientsfeedback` WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."' GROUP BY manager ORDER BY `manager` ASC");
```

----- EDIT -----

You would probably be best to get these values with a single sql query instead of nesting 2 queries in loops, for example

```
$m = '09';

include "dbconnect.php";

$sql = ("SELECT manager, COUNT(manager) as managercount, SUM(totalscore) AS totalscore FROM clientsfeedback WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '".$m."' GROUP BY manager ORDER BY manager ASC");

$result=mysql_query($sql); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['manager']."</td><td>".$row['managercount']."</td><td>".$row['totalscore']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: I now get two results rather than the count increase For example:

Comment: Bennett 1 18, Bennett 1 22, Bloggs 1 10

Comment: In stead of Bennett 2 40, Bloggs 1 10

Comment: Did you try the second expression in my answer above? The mysql count will return the number of rows so you don't need to do this `$ct = count($count);` and you can use the `$count` directly in your `echo ` line

Comment: if you leave count as $count you get this "Select count(manager) FROM clientsfeedback WHERE MONTH(submitteddate) = '09' AND manager = 'Bennett'" and yes with your bit of code i entered still got the same issue

Comment: I've updated the answer for getting a list of unique managers

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a single `SELECT` query, which should retrieve the values

Comment: So close however we now have Bennett 2 34, Bennett 1 14. No Bloggs but the scores are correct which is werid.

Comment: can you post a sample of the data that you are using with these 3 managers?

Comment: Thanks, with that schema, it returns Bennett 2 32, Manager2 1 14 which would be correct?